# Avoiding warning messages when using bit shifting to extract parts of a word

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Assuming that data.msg is a pointer to an array of longs(64 bit), 
why is this giving me the warning below.

```
uint16_t messageSize = 0;
messageSize |= (uint16_t)(data.msg[0] & 0x00000000000000FF);
```

output

```
warning: convertion to 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from 'int'
```

If I remove the cast to uint16_t I get the same message with the exception that it says long instead of int.  Regardless, I am getting the correct values and only losing precision I want to loose but I am trying to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: what's the type of  `msg`?

Comment: data.msg is a pointer to an array of longs.

Comment: `convertion` ? are you sure? [mcve], cannot reproduce here. (tried clang & gcc with all warnings on)

Comment: what about `(uint8_t)(data.msg[0])` ? that would be simpler and does the same thing.

Comment: If you look up stdint.h, uint8_t is actually an unsigned char which also generates it's own equally annoying but harmless complaints.

Comment: what about a [mcve] ? no one seems able to reproduce your warning. Also state the name & the version of your compiler. Unless it's a linter ?*

Comment: It does beg the question, why the array of int if you're only using the one byte?

Comment: Note that 0x00000000000000FF and 0xFF are the same value and the same type; the extra zeros make no difference.

Comment: Note that `a |= b` is a shorthand for `a = a | b` except that `a` is evaluated once (which matters if `a` is actually spelled `t->p[q++]->r[j--]` or something baroque, if not broken, like that).  Given that `a | b` is evaluated by promoting both arguments to `int` and then evaluating the expression, the assignment is shortening the `int` result and triggering the message.  Your cast doesn't change the expression.  Try `messagesize = (uint16_t)(messagesize | (data.msg[0] & 0xFF));` -- that cast might avoid the shortening conversion message,

Comment: Set your compiler to shop showing this useless warning

Comment: Jonathan Leffler,  excellent observation. Definately worth keeping in mind but the -Wconversion flag will still flag this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting these warnings because somewhere within your make file someone is using the flag "-Wconversion". This is a very conservative flag that warns of the *possibility* of precision loss. This does not mean anything is actually wrong with the values.

The more common flags ( -Wall, -Werror, -Pendactic) do not call           -Wconversion.  As far as I know it has to be called explicitly.

I wrote a sample which should be pretty similar to the behavior you described:

```
uint8_t func(uint16_t i)
{
    uint8_t out = 0;
    out |= i;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    long l;
    uint8_t i;
    l = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;  // -1 (unsigned)
    printf("Initial Long: %ld\n", l);
    i = func(l);
    printf("8 bits: %d\n", i);  // value: 255
}
```

I tried multiple c and c++ standards.  I'm only getting warnings when
-Wconversion is used. This code does exactly what it is supposed to.  As long as you are getting the values you are looking for I would question if the -Wconversion needs to be in he make file, or use a #pragma to ignore it like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
```